# Assigning the result of group by to items in a list with linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an

```
IEnumerable<typeA> result;
```

from this result I need to get sum group by some id.

So I have the query

```
 var groupeddata = from data in result
                      group data by data.Title
                      into grouped
                      select new { intid= grouped.Key,
                                   expsum= grouped.Sum(x=>x.expnum)};
```

now this expsum I need to assign to the items of result where typeA.id is same as intid. Now how to do this assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to use a dictionary:

```
var sumDictionary = query.ToDictionary(pair => pair.intid, pair => pair.expsum);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    // We don't know which property you actually want to assign to
    item.Sum = sumDictionary[item.id];
}
```

Comment: I wish to assign the sum to property expnum where the property title is same as the intid

Comment: @xaria: You're still not really being clear, but it sounds like my answer should be fine - just change `item.Sum` to whatever property you want to set.

Comment: I came across this code result.ToList().ForEach( item => { item.expnum = groupeddata .Where(c => c.intid == item.Title) .FirstOrDefault() .expsum; });    But the problem with this is that with every iteration the groupeddata is being computed again and the value is not as expected. Why will groupeddata be computed again>

Comment: @xaria: Firstly, I'd recommend against using `ForEach` like this. Use the `foreach` statement - it's considerably simpler. The reason it's computing the sum each time is that `groupeddata` is lazily evaluated. Read tutorials on LINQ to find out more about that. I don't know why you didn't just use my answer though - it would be more efficient even after materializing the grouping.

Comment: It's not about using your answer or not. I came across a different approach and tried it out, and realised it didn't work as it was supposed to. And hence the curiosity. I am new to Linq and trying to learn. Anyways I did mark your reply as answer!